# C++ Dimensional Analysis (Barnes and Nackman) with Scale

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I was recently reading the series on the C++ Source, “A Pause to Reflect: Five Lists of Five”. In [Part V](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_aha_moments.html), Scott Meyers discusses the Barton and Nackman solution to the units problem. As an embedded software engineer for the aerospace industry, this particular Aha! Moment got me excited. Up until this point I’ve not heard of this approach (nor these authors).

I have done research trying to find more information regarding the solution. I came across this presentation here: http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/OTHERS/scott_meyers/dimensions.pdf

I think I understand everything that I have read on this solution. But I feel like there is a piece of the puzzle missing. Nowhere does this beautiful, elegant solution address scale. Specifically I am interested in conversions that are more than just a multiplication factor. For example, Temperature converting between Kelvin, Celsius, and Fahrenheit. I would like to be able to use these temperatures interchangeably.

My Questions:

1. Did I miss something? Is scale discussed somewhere in reference to the Units solution discussion that I have overlooked?
2. If not, How could I approach this problem further? Is there an existing pattern that could be used in combination with the B&N approach to complete the solution?

My Goal is to be able code that looks something like the below example without excessive computations. In the case of distance, I want to be able to declare an object defined as a mile, and perform all my relevant calculations as miles, without having to constantly to convert back and forth to meters.

Example:

```
typedef Units<double, miles>      uMiles;
typedef Units<double, kilometers> uKilometers;

uMiles      d1 (1.0);
uKilometers d2 (1.60934);

d1 += d2;
if (d1.val(miles) == 2.0) // PASS
if (d1.val(kilometers) == 3.21869) // PASS
```

Note:
I have seen the BOOST UNITS solution to the problem and I don’t like it. To me it is very unreadable. Nor am I, typically allowed to use external libraries such as boost.

**Backup Data:**

The Units Class as described:

```
template<class T, // Precision
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a> // Angle

    class Units
    {
    public:
    // ------------------------------------------------------
    explicit
    Units (T initVal = 0)
        : val (initVal)
    {
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Operator: Assignment from type T
    Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>&
    operator= (const T rhs)
    {
        val = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Operator: Type Converstion to T
    operator T () const
    {
        return val;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Operator: +=
    Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>&
    operator+= (const Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>& rhs)
    {
        val += rhs.val;
        return *this;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>&
    operator-= (const Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>& rhs)
    {
        val -= rhs.val;
        return *this;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>&
    operator*= (T rhs)
    {
        val *= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>&
    operator/= (T rhs)
    {
        val /= rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get Reference
    T&
    Val ()
    {
        return val;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get Value
    const T&
    Val () const
    {
        return val;
    }

    private:
    T val;
    };

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Addition
template<class T, int m, int d, int t, int q, int k, int i, int a>
    const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a>
    operator+ (const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & lhs,
           const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & rhs)
    {
    Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> result (lhs);
    return result += rhs;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Subtraction
template<class T, int m, int d, int t, int q, int k, int i, int a>
    const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a>
    operator- (const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & lhs,
           const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & rhs)
    {
    Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> result (lhs);
    return result -= rhs;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Multiplication
template<class T, int m, int d, int t, int q, int k, int i, int a>
    const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a>
    operator* (const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & lhs,
           const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & rhs)
    {
    Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> result (lhs);
    return result *= rhs;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Division
template<class T, int m, int d, int t, int q, int k, int i, int a>
    const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a>
    operator/ (const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & lhs,
           const Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> & rhs)
    {
    Units<T, m, d, t, q, k, i, a> result (lhs);
    return result /= rhs;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Multiplication (Creates New Type)
template<class T,
        int m1, int d1, int t1, int q1, int k1, int i1, int a1,
    int m2, int d2, int t2, int q2, int k2, int i2, int a2>

    // Return Type
    Units<T, m1 + m2, d1 + d2, t1 + t2, q1 + q2, k1 + k2, i1 + i2, a1 + a2>
    operator* (const Units<T, m1, d1, t1, q1, k1, i1, a1>& lhs,
           const Units<T, m2, d2, t2, q2, k2, i2, a2>& rhs)
    {
        // New Return type
    typedef Units<T,
        m1 + m2,
        d1 + d2,
        t1 + t2,
        q1 + q2,
        k1 + k2,
        i1 + i2,
        a1 + a2> ResultType;

    return ResultType (lhs.Val() * rhs.Val());
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Operator: Division (Creates New Type)
template<class T,
        int m1, int d1, int t1, int q1, int k1, int i1, int a1,
    int m2, int d2, int t2, int q2, int k2, int i2, int a2>

    // Return Type
    Units<T, m1 - m2, d1 - d2, t1 - t2, q1 - q2, k1 - k2, i1 - i2, a1 - a2>
    operator/ (const Units<T, m1, d1, t1, q1, k1, i1, a1>& lhs,
           const Units<T, m2, d2, t2, q2, k2, i2, a2>& rhs)
    {
        // New Return type
    typedef Units<
        T,
        m1 - m2,
        d1 - d2,
        t1 - t2,
        q1 - q2,
        k1 - k2,
        i1 - i2,
        a1 - a2> ResultType;

    return ResultType (lhs.Val() / rhs.Val());
    }
```

This class allows us to write code that looks like this:

```
//  Base Types
typedef Units<double, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0> uMass;
typedef Units<double, 0,1,0,0,0,0,0> uLength;
typedef Units<double, 0,0,1,0,0,0,0> uTime;
typedef Units<double, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0> uCharge;
typedef Units<double, 0,0,0,0,1,0,0> uTemperature;
typedef Units<double, 0,0,0,0,0,1,0> uIntensity;
typedef Units<double, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1> uAngle;

//  Derived Types
typedef Units<double, 0,2, 0,0,0,0,0> uArea;
typedef Units<double, 0,3, 0,0,0,0,0> uVolume;
typedef Units<double, 0,1,-1,0,0,0,0> uVelocity;
typedef Units<double, 0,1,-2,0,0,0,0> uAcceleration;
typedef Units<double, 1,1,-2,0,0,0,0> uForce;


uMass         mass;
uTime         time;
uForce        force;
uLength       length;
uVelocity     velocity;
uAcceleration acceleration;

// This will compile
mass = 7.2;
acceleration = 3.5;
force = mass * acceleration;

// These will not compile ** Enforcing Dimensional Unit Correctness
force = 7.2 * acceleration;
force = mass; 
force *= acceleration;
```

Comment: I do want to note that I have purchased the book that Scott Meyers references by Barton and Nackman. I am hoping that this book provides more insight as well. http://www.amazon.com/Scientific-Engineering-Introduction-Advanced-Techniques/dp/0201533936/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424790308&sr=8-1&keywords=Barton+Nackman

Comment: Units are things that can be combined multiplicatively. Degree scales are not (since they have an arbitrary zero point that doesn't mean "nothing"), so I wouldn't expect a "units" library to handle them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I disagree. All Units have implicit scale. I am just looking for a way to be explicit and provide a way to convert. Boost Units also provides scale, albeit in a ugly way.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I agree. Really you could say the same thing about converting between any different unit systems.  You would not be able to use the above code to even convert between centimeters and inches or milliliters and fluid ounces because of how the operators are overloaded.  Unless maybe you created "Units" that were really just constants like `Unit<double, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0> constant(243);` and then you could maybe do something like `celsius=kelvin-constant`

Comment: @mstbaum perhaps my question wasnt clear? I know I cant convert between any scales for any units with the above library. Temperature is just a particular point of interest for me because its not a straight multiplicative conversion. My question is meant to help me drive the above design into something new that supports scale combined with units. The ultimate goal is for a solution it to be simple and scale-able, which is why I wanted to start with the Barnes and Nackman solution. For straight DA with no concern for scale, it is extremly elegant and enforces compile time conformance.

Comment: @Jerunh: If by "scale" you mean "zero point", then all units have a zero point representing "nothing" (no mass, no distance, etc.), which is why they can be combined with multiplication, which is why a type like this is useful. Non-units, like degrees Fahrenheit, have a zero point representing some arbitrary amount, and can't be simply combined with units. If you want to support them, you need something that isn't a unit, which isn't what you'd expect from a "unit" type like this.

Comment: What is the point of `Units<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>& operator= (const T rhs)`

Comment: @NeilKirk: To allow assignments like `mass = 7.2;` in the example. Although arguably it might be better to only have an explicit constructor to force you write a more self-documenting `mass = kilograms(7.2);`

Comment: @mikeSeymour I'm not sure I understand your point of contention regarding Temperature as units and Scales. The International System of Units defines seven base units, of which temperature (measured in kelvin ) is one of them. I would expect all units libraries that handle all other SI units to also handle Temperature. If your contention is the Fahrenheit scale, I would argue that the point of 0 is not arbitrary, but rather a function of the boiling and freezing point of water. But still, I'm not sure either point is valid.

Comment: @Jerunh: Kelvin is a unit because its zero point represents "no temperature" - it's an absolute scale. Fahrenheit isn't a unit - hence "degrees F" not just "F" - because its zero point is an arbitrary function of some physical properties, as you say, and doesn't represent "no temperature". You can meaningfully multiply absolute units to get other units (e.g. the Ideal Gas Law `pV = kT` makes sense for absolute temperature), but not relative quantities for which zero isn't a multiplicative zero.

Comment: @mikeseymour So if measures don't converge at zero then they aren't "units"?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Oh I see, I didn't spot the constructor is explicit.

Comment: @Jerunh: Yes, that's right. Units are things you can multiply to make other (compound) units; this `Units` class models that multiplicative combination. If zero doesn't mean zero, then multiplication doesn't make sense, so the quantity isn't a "unit".

Comment: I know it's an old question, but if you are looking for a fully featured, tested, and verified units library you could check out https://github.com/nholthaus/units. You Full disclosure, I wrote it. At a minimum, it gives some ideas about how to do the datum shifting required for temperature conversions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your code and your explanation, it would seem you could define conversion constant "`Unit`s" such as

```
Units<double,0,0,0,0,0,0,0> K2C(243.15);
Units<double,0,0,0,0,1,0,0> uCelsius;
Units<double,0,0,0,0,1,0,0> uKelvin;

uCelsius = uKelvin - K2C;
```

The above code works with the overloaded operator while keeping the templated units consistent.  You would have to create pseudo-`Unit`s for any constants you want to use.

The other way I could see working would be writing a function like

```
typdef enum {
    CELSIUS,
    KELVIN,
    FAHRENHEIT
} temp_t;

void Units::convertTemp(const temp_t from, const temp_t to) {

    switch(from) {
        case KELVIN:
            val -= 243.15;
        case CELSIUS:
            if(to == FAHRENHEIT)
                //conversion
            else if(to == KELVIN)
                val += 243.15;
            break;
        case FAHRENHEIT:
            // convert to celsius
            if(to == KELVIN)
                //convert to Kelvin
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't meet my expectations of being able to use the Units interchangeably. Both solutions your provide require explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In physics a value that has a unit, like speed, when multiplied by a scalar retains its unit. This means that saying something like:

```
1.6 * 7 kilometers per hour = 11.2 kilometers per hour
```

doesn't change the units. What we actually wanted to do is convert kilometers per hour to miles per hour but instead we simply multiplied kilometers per hour by a factor. Just because the number that you get is equivalent to miles per hour doesn't mean that you're actually representing miles per hour.

In your template definition you only ever allow for **one kind of each of the basic units**.

So far, you have differentiated between different kinds of physical quantities but not between different kinds of unit systems. In the code above, your unit/type is `Speed`, not `milesPerHour`, and you're still manually remembering what actual unit you are using and converting between it and the SI units by hand *(not using the type system)*. Effectively, if you had one variable initialized to miles per hour and the other to kilometers per hour, would they have the same type or different type? I will argue that they should be different types.

To make all of the units *(in different systems of measurement)* different types we could write one `Units` template for the [SI units system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), and an equivalent one for the [Imperial units system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_units).

```
template<class T, // Precision
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a> // Angle

    class SIUnits
    {
    // ...

template<class T, // Precision
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a> // Angle

    class ImperialUnits
    {
    // ...
```

Now we need to figure out a good way to allow our type system to automatically map us between the two unit systems.

The following is one possible *(but terrible)* solution:

```
template<class T, // Precision
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a> // Angle

    ImperialUnits<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a>
    convert(SIUnits<T, m, l, t, q, k, i, a> value)
    {
        T conversionFactor = 1.0;
        for (int x = 0; x < m; ++x)
        {
            // This is some function that maps from one to the other.
            conversionFactor *= siMassToImperialMassFactor;
            conversionFactor += siMassToImperialMassOffset;
        }

        for (int x = m; x < 0; ++x)
        {
            // This is some function that maps from one to the other.
            conversionFactor *= siMassToImperialMassFactor;
            conversionFactor += siMassToImperialMassOffset;
        }

        // Do the same for other dimensions as well...
```

The problem that you are seeing with Kelvin, Fahrenheit, and Celsius is to do with the fact that you are not changing the underlying system of measurements, which would require you to make a new type, but are merely manually remembering the fiddle factor that is required to pretend to convert between the two systems.

In essence, if we removed the templates and used pure classes we would have something like:

```
class Celsius;
class Kelvin;
class Fahrenheit
{
    // ...
    Fahrenheit(Celsius t); // Auto-convert from celsius
    Fahrenheit(Kelvin t);  // Auto-convert from Kelvin
    // ...
```

These are different types so that we can use the type system to define the conversions between them.

Finally, I can explain what I am actually proposing. In your `Units` template you have the underlying type and identifiers for each of the physical dimensions and one of the solutions would be to add one more item to denote the system of measurements that is used, i.e.

```
template<class T, // Precision
    int SystemOfUnits, // Denotes the system of units used, SI or Imperial.
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a> // Angle

    class Units
    {
        // etc.
```

However, I don't like the above solution as the value of the `SystemOfUnits` template parameter encodes too much information about your template. I would probably be more explicit in my definition stating exactly what units my system of measurement uses, i.e.

```
template<class T, // Precision
    int m, // Mass
    int l, // Length
    int t, // Time
    int q, // Charge
    int k, // Temperature
    int i, // Luminous Intensity
    int a, // Angle
    class M, // Mass unit type
    class L, // Length unit type
    class T, // Time unit type
    class Q, // Charge unit type
    class K, // Temperature unit type
    class I, // Luminous Intensity unit type
    class A> // Angle unit type


    class Units
    {
        // etc.
```

Which would force you to use a consistent system of measurement for dimensional analysis at the cost of doubling your template arguments.